# C++ DLL not loading debug symbols

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, debug-symbols

In my solution I have two projects: one is a C++ DLL, and the other is a C# Windows Forms EXE (with the latter having a build dependency on the former). The DLL gets linked in correctly and works (my test function returns the right number, at least). The actually useful functionality is throwing an exception somewhere, but I can't debug it because none of the debug symbols for the C++ project are being loaded.

The PDB is definitely being generated! The EXE, DLL and PDB are all in the same folder. I even added their directory as one of the symbol file locations (Options > Debugging > Symbols), but this didn't do anything.

Apparently, the Modules window is supposed to tell you something, but my DLL doesn't appear there (yet it still works fine).

I'm using a x64 DLL with no compiled headers, if that makes any difference.

Compiler commandline:

```
/GS /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"E:\Users\Sean\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusicStreamingClient\MusicStreamingClient\RapidJson\include\" /ZI /Gm /Od /Fd"x64\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_DEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL" /D "MUSICSTREAMINGCLIENT_EXPORTS" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MDd /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\MusicStreamingClient.pch"
```

Linker commandline:

```
/OUT:"E:\Users\Sean\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusicStreamingClient\x64\Debug\MusicStreamingClient.dll" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"E:\Users\Sean\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusicStreamingClient\x64\Debug\MusicStreamingClient.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "E:\Users\Sean\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusicStreamingClient\MusicStreamingClient\RapidJson\x64\Debug\RapidJson.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /IMPLIB:"E:\Users\Sean\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusicStreamingClient\x64\Debug\MusicStreamingClient.lib" /DLL /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"E:\Users\Sean\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusicStreamingClient\x64\Debug\MusicStreamingClient.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\MusicStreamingClient.dll.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently debugging Managed code only.  Native symbols will not be visible.  You need to change your debug option to enable both Managed and Native modes for your project.